# How to keep a specific option at the end of dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, struts2

I would like to show a list of cities to users to choose from, users should also be able to choose "Other" option to add a new city. Once they choose 'other' a new textbox would be shown to get the value of the new option.

The problem is that 'Other' option should always be the last option in the list, but the order of the list is based on id numbers. Even if I make it the last item in the cities table, because users are able to add new cities, all new cities would go after 'Other' in the list.

```
<s:select list="Cities"
             name="cities.id"
             label="Cities"
   />
```

**List**

in database the list of cities is like the following

```
 Paris
 Los Angeles 
 Other
```

However, it should be shown to users like following (Ordered, while other would remain the last option)

```
 Los Angeles
 Paris
 Other
```

If other is choosen and Tokyo is typed updated list should be (Ordered, Tokyo is added, while Other is still the last option)

```
    Los Angeles
    Paris
    Tokyo
    Other
```

Comment: Try getting only the cities from the DB and hard code the `Other` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1. Add the option dynamically via JS
2. Add that option in the action (or wherever the cities are loaded) by appending it to `Cities`
3. Don't use the `<s:select>` tag, just build the options for a plain HTML select

I'd probably go with option two, simply adding the option to the list before the JSP is rendered.

Whether or not that's the *best* approach depends on other aspects of your app.

---

Unrelated, but ordering by IDs seems highly counter-intuitive.